# Parallel sequential scan on compicated join

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have following SQL (simplified and anonymized for easier understanding)

```
select max(db.tableA."id")
from db.tableA
         left outer join db.tableB
                         on (db.tableB.column1 = db.tableA.column1
                            and db.tableB.column2 = db.tableA.column2
                            and db.tableB.column3 = db.tableA.column3
                            and db.tableB.column4 = db.tableA.column4)
where (db.tableA.column1 = 'SOME_VALUE'
       and db.tableA.column2 in ('some', 'list', 'of', 'values')
       and db.tableB.column2 is null)
```

This SQL runs sometimes even 20 seconds for some reason. When I use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, I see something I don't really understand.

```
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=11704.05..11704.06 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=62.069..62.110 rows=1 loops=5)
              ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=34.58..11679.12 rows=9970 width=8) (actual time=62.064..62.105 rows=0 loops=5)
                    Hash Cond: ((_hyper_1_11005_chunk.column1= tableB.column1) AND (_hyper_1_11005_chunk.column2= tableB.column2) AND (_hyper_1_11005_chunk.column3= tableB.column3) AND (_hyper_1_11005_chunk.column4= tableB.column4))
                    ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.02..11369.08 rows=11389 width=29) (actual time=0.038..47.278 rows=11262 loops=5)
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_11005_chunk  (cost=0.02..462.20 rows=1667 width=29) (actual time=0.041..13.213 rows=2834 loops=1)
"                                Filter: ((column1= 'SOME_VALUE'::text) AND (column2= ANY ('{'some', 'list', 'of', 'values'}'::text[])))"
```

**And this list continues a long way down with a lot of** `Parallel Seq Scan` steps (each with same condition, only on another chunk)

---

Indices on tables that contains any columns in SQL above are (indices for primary keys are omitted for simplicity)

**TableA**

- (column1, column2, column3, column4)

**TableB**

- (column1, column2)

I am probably missing some index or something because I think that this SQL is not that complex to run for several seconds but I have no clue what I am missing, can anyone help me understand why PostgreSQL using multiple sequential scans to join these tables together?

**PostgreSQL version is 14.5**

---

**EDIT:** As requested, result of analyse with verbose, settings, buffers is like following (pasted via pastebin due to its length
[Explain result](https://pastebin.com/qweexixF)

Comment: table be must have also an index on all 4 columns

Comment: @nbk Thanks for the answer, I´ve added index to each table to have indices for (column1..column4) but explain analyze still shows a lot of parralel seq scans

Comment: actual time=62.069..62.110, this is measured in milliseconds. This is not your problem when you're talking about 20 seconds delay. Could you share the entire (anonymous) query plan using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your complete statement?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Hi, thanks for your comment. I see that execution of this SQL alone is pretty fast, but problem is that while app is under pressure (for example while running tests), execution time is pretty high (10-29 seconds). And the amount of scans needed to join tables looks like a possible problem that may cause these delays while database is under heavy loads. I´ve added result of enhanced explain in the edit section.

Comment: the in clause is probably the cause, as it needs to check all rows if they match

Comment: @nbk Is there any way how to bypass this? Or how to help database perform this action quicker?

Comment: i find your query quite bad, as i have a hard time to understand without seeing the data. when is `db.tableB.column2 is null` somtimes or only because of the left join
?

Comment: as i see it, you can remove the join and replace it with a not  exists and see if that is faster(which it should be)

Comment: @nbk You mean like filter tableA results by column1 and column2 and then somehow filter out tableA records by subquery on tableB? But how would I pair that together as there is no simple relation between these two tables?

Comment: What is the purpose of "db.tableB.column2 is null"? If it is to filter out all records where the join didn't find a match in tableB then you can replace this with an INNER join. If you think that the LEFT JOIN is going to match records, some of which will have NULL in column2 and you want to filter these out then that is not the case as your join has already filtered out any records where this column is null

Comment: The sequential scans are not the problem, it's the Gather that takes 70% of the time needed. What happens when you change the setting for max_parallel_workers_per_gather? Set it first to 0 (zero) and then increase to something else. What works best?

Comment: The plan you show is 100 times faster than 20 seconds.  You will have to capture a case of it being slow to figure out why it is slow.  It can't just simply be the fault of the existence of a parallel seq scan, because otherwise this current plan would be slow.

Answer (score 0):

As i wrote, if clomun2 has always values, you can try

```
select max(db.tableA."id")
from db.tableA       
where (db.tableA.column1 = 'SOME_VALUE'
       and db.tableA.column2 in ('some', 'list', 'of', 'values')
       and NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM  db.tableB
                         WHERE (db.tableB.column1 = db.tableA.column1
                            and db.tableB.column2 = db.tableA.column2
                            and db.tableB.column3 = db.tableA.column3
                            and db.tableB.column4 = db.tableA.column4))
```

and if that doesn't make it haster, you can always split the IN clause ind separate `SELECT`s and `UNION ALL` them, so that the Full scan can be avoided, that is of course only when the list is small